# Can WhatsApp be intercepted?

Tags: encryption, whatsapp

Is it possible to intercept/hack a WhatsApp conversation between two people or messages sent to a group and how safe is WhatsApp call? Is eaves dropping possible in anyway?

Comment: This question is somewhat like asking "can people break into my house?". It's probably possible (in this case by Facebook themselves or a government agency). But is it feasible by a random cyber criminal? probably not. The story changes if your phone is infected, then however secure WhatsApp is, an attacker can read what you do.

Comment: If you are using What's app from the start then I hope you will not stop using What's app if you come to know that its E2E is compromised by the government.

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp has an end-to-end encryption feature, this should protect you from *most* threats.

Here's another thing, WhatsApp is compromised by NSA. Its mother company, Facebook, has been proven to be in NSA's PRISM program. So, if the NSA is in your threat model then I'd advise to avoid WhatsApp and use a more security-oriented OTR software, like Signal, or Wire.

Comment: citation needed for the NSA to have compromised the E2E encryption of WhatsApp ...

Comment: @schroeder  history has proven that the compromises disclosure needs time.

Comment: @elsadek he made the claim, he needs to back it up

Comment: @schroeder https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=we-pJE5JjAs

Comment: @bigbadprogrammer sorry, that is not proof that "WhatsApp is compromised by NSA"